# Tell Hibernate not to drop entities of library project

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a library project called *COMMON*. *COMMON* is deployed to our company artifactory and is used by many other projects. In *COMMON* I have a few common entities. In one of the newer projects that does not yet have a database connection we see this error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl: HHH000478: Unsuccessful: drop table myschema.my_table if exists
```

This is frightening as these entities are not to be dropped. They are not even to be modified at line level as they are marked with `@Immutable`.

In the projects that use *COMMON* as a dependency I can tell hibernate not to do this with the following setting in application.properties: 
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

The problem with this is, that in project *A* if I want to use the ddl-auto feature on my *A* specific entities but not on the *COMMON* ones, I can't do that with this approach. Also if a dev forgets to add this property we drop the tables.

**Can we restrict an Entity from being dropped/created in hibernate?**

Comment: Maybe you found a good reason that this library does not make much sense? In my opinion it is a bad practice for a library to use Beans or even worse Entities.

Comment: @TobiasOtto So how would you reuse the same entities over different Java projects? What is the alternative here?